# Change the default settings for @Transactional in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Currently, we have to add `rollbackFor=Exception.class` for 90% of the methods in our application that use `@Transactional` annotation. I was wondering if there is a way to set the default for `rollbackFor` to `Exception.class` somewhere so that we don't have to explicitly specify it every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is an annotation, the standard is writing your own custom annotation and replacing it with `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)`. If you annotate with the following annotation you don't need to specify `rollbackFor` in everywhere because it will be implied.

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
@Documented
public @interface CustomTransactional {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, there is no other global way of setting it in Spring?

Comment: As far as I know, no.